# `git submodule update` doesn't checkout the commit in the submodule

Tags: git

I've got following problem: When I'm checkout out a specific commit of the superproject and run `git update submodules`, the commit of the submodule is not checked out, although that is what this command should do according to the manpage, internet blog posts and so on. I still manually have to run `git submodule <path/to/submodule>` to check the correct commit out.

Does anyone know what I could be that makes git behave that way? I'm using `git version 2.11.0`.

---

Working tree is clean.

```
manuel@manuelthinkpad:~/projects/testcompile/superproject$ git status
HEAD detached at origin/master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

The right commit for submodule `problematic_submodule` is checked out. (Its line is not prefixed with `+`/`-`.)

```
manuel@manuelthinkpad:~/projects/testcompile/superproject$ git submodule
+321fce0da25208bf886d85ce4a2f1cefc02bbfff modules/libgksl (v1.2-9-g321fce0)
 ... some other modules ...
 9acb4a5d28d1ac785fce17799d58e21cc437b77d modules/problematic_submodule (v0.19-3355-g9acb4a5d2)
```

I'm checkout out the local master of the superproject, which is not yet pushed:

```
manuel@manuelthinkpad:~/projects/testcompile/superproject$ git checkout master
Previous HEAD position was 4b58c94... Merge branch 'dev' into 'master'
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

Now I want to update the submodules so they have the correct commits checked out:

```
manuel@manuelthinkpad:~/projects/testcompile/superproject$ git submodule update --recursive
Fetched in submodule path 'modules/libgksl', but it did not contain a20f22f989afbcbb620303a6b418de8093c71259. Direct fetching of that commit failed.
```

Alas, `problematic_submodule` is still on the wrong commit. (Note that the line is prefixed with an `+`.)

```
manuel@manuelthinkpad:~/projects/testcompile/superproject$ git submodule
+321fce0da25208bf886d85ce4a2f1cefc02bbfff modules/libgksl (v1.2-9-g321fce0)
 ... some other modules ...
+9acb4a5d28d1ac785fce17799d58e21cc437b77d modules/problematic_submodule (v0.19-3355-g9acb4a5d2)
```

I have to specify `problematic_submodule` so it gets checked out:

```
manuel@manuelthinkpad:~/projects/testcompile/superproject$ git submodule update modules/problematic_submodule/
Submodule path 'modules/problematic_submodule': checked out '24b46f28edf9c75bf8a7bcf4cac7aa65564c88c9'
```

Only now the correct commit of `problematic_submodule` is checked out. (The line is no longer prefixed with an `+`.)

```
manuel@manuelthinkpad:~/projects/testcompile/superproject$ git submodule
+321fce0da25208bf886d85ce4a2f1cefc02bbfff modules/libgksl (v1.2-9-g321fce0)
 ... some other modules
 24b46f28edf9c75bf8a7bcf4cac7aa65564c88c9 modules/problematic_submodule (v0.19-3551-g24b46f28e)
```

Comment: Would you tell what are the commands you gave to check out the specific commit in that git submdoule?

Comment: `Fetched in submodule path 'modules/libgksl', but it did not contain a20f22f989afbcbb620303a6b418de8093c71259. Direct fetching of that commit failed` This sounds like an error message to me. Maybe the whole command cancels because of this error for submodule `modules/libgksl`? Does `git submodule update modules/problematic_submodule` work?

Comment: @LethalProgrammer: I don't know what you mean. The line `9acb4a5d28d1ac785fce17799d58e21cc437b77d modules/problematic_submodule (v0.19-3355-g9acb4a5d2)` is not prefixed with `+` or `-`, so the correct commit submodule is checked out.

Comment: I mean are you using `git checkout <commit-id>` ?, After doing this you got the error?

Comment: @kowsky: It seems your assumption that 'the whole command cancels because of this error for submodule `modules/libgksl`' is correct. As for the question if `git submodule update modules/problematic_submodule` works: This is answered in my initial post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the reason for `git submodule update` failing to checkout the correct commit in submodule `problematic_submodule` was that it aborted when not being able to checkout the desired commit for submodule `libgksl`.

```
manuel@manuelthinkpad:~/projects/testcompile/superproject$ git submodule update --recursive
Fetched in submodule path 'modules/libgksl', but it did not contain a20f22f989afbcbb620303a6b418de8093c71259. Direct fetching of that commit failed.
```

Apparantly, this stopped the whole submodule update action.

I was able to resolve my problem by conducting following steps:

1.
Changing into `modules/libgksl` and checking-out an existing commit.

2.
Going back into the superproject, `git add modules/libgksl`, and committing.

Now the superproject is in a healthy state again. When I change the checked-out commit of a submodule and store its SHA1 in the superproject by adding and committing, `git submodule update` is from now on able to update the submodule accordingly.